# SQL Server Full Text Search With NULL Parameters - performace hit

Tags: stored-procedures, sql-server-2012, full-text-search, query-optimization

I'm trying to use `Contains()` in a search procedure. The full text indexes are created and working. The issue arises because you cannot used `Contains()` call on a `NULL` variable or parameter, it throws an error.

This takes 9 sec to run (passing in non-null param):

```
--Solution I saw on another post    
IF @FirstName is null OR @FirstName = '' SET @FirstName = '""'
    ...
    Select * from [MyTable] m
    Where
    (@FirstName = '""' OR CONTAINS(m.[fname], @FirstName))
```

This runs instantly (passing in non-null param)

```
IF @FirstName is null OR @FirstName = '' SET @FirstName = '""'
...
Select * from [MyTable] m
Where
CONTAINS(m.[fname], @FirstName)
```

Just by adding that extra 'OR' in front of the 'contains' completely changed the Query Plan. I have also tried using a 'case' statement instead of 'OR' to no avail, I still get the slow query.

Has anyone solved this the problem of null parameters in full text searching or experience my issue? Any thoughts would help, thanks.

I'm using SQL Server 2012

Comment: These 2 queries return the same results?

Comment: Yes they return the same results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are checking value of bind variable in SQL. Even worse, you do it in OR with access predicate. I am not an expert on SQL Server, but it is generally a bad practice, and such predicates lead to full table scans.

If you really need to select all values from table when `@FirstName` is null then check it outside of SQL query.

```
IF @FirstName is null 
  <query-without-CONTAINS>
ELSE
  <query-with-CONTAINS>
```

I believe, in the majority of times `@FirstName` is not null. This way you will access table using your full text index most of the time. Getting all the rows from table is a lost cause anyway.

Comment: ok thanks, so it is not possible to do what I want? to have a null check and not run the Contains() whenI don't need to? This is just a snippet of the actual proc, I have about 8 full text search parameters coming in, most will probably be null. I guess I will have to use a dynamic sql to build a string up and then do EXEC sp_executesql. That would basically do what you are saying without repeating so much code.

Comment: Basically, you will end up performing full table scans all the time, so I'd say it's not a good idea. Dynamic SQL to add `CONTAINS` only when needed looks fine.

Answer (score 0):

From a logical standpoint, the first query takes longer to execute because it has to evaluate 2 conditions:

```
@FirstName = '""'
```

and ,in case the first condition fails, which should be the majority of the time,

```
CONTAINS(m.[fname], @FirstName)
```

My guess is that in your table, you don't have any null or empty FirstName, that's why the results are the same. Otherwise, you would have a few "" in the result set as FirstName.

Maybe you should try reversing the order to see if it makes any difference:

```
WHERE (CONTAINS(m.[fname], @FirstName) OR @FirstName = '""')
```

Comment: For instance in both of these queries I'm passing in "Chris" as @FirstName. Both results are exactly the same. All the 2nd query is doing is checking to see if the parameter is blank before trying to run the Contains() part to ensure that a NULL is not passed which would result in an error.

Comment: Thanks for the ideas. The problem with reversing the order is that I lose my "short circuit" when my parameter is actually null, then I'd get an error. Having the check first bypasses having to call Contains() at all

Comment: I'm confused. When your parameter is null, isn't FirstName set to double quotes, as in your IF statement?

Comment: Yes it's set to double quotes when null. When the parameter is null I want it to return everything, when there is a value for @FirstName I want it to use the "Contains()" method to filter down my results.

Comment: Then you should probably just set it to empty string ( ' ' ) instead of double quotes, and omit the @FirstName condition in your WHERE clause. Alternatively, follow thatYoungMan's answer..